# Построение предложения

Tags: общие-вопросы

В газете читаю: Так и мы разделили предприятия на тех, кто будет испытывать трудности, и тех, кто в новых условиях получает шанс сделать мощный рывок вперед.
Я считаю, что в предложении допущены ошибки, например, вместо тех нужно использовать на те, и мне не нравится время глагола получает. Правильно ли я думаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, мне это важно.

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Согласна с вами. Слово "предприятия" неодушевленное, поэтому "...предприятия на те, которые...". 
 По поводу времени глагола - время должно быть одинаковое. Например, "будет испытывать" и "получит"

Comment: Несоответствие времён - грамматическая ошибка, но иногда является стилистическим приёмом. "кто в новых условиях получает шанс сделать мощный рывок вперед" вполне можно к нему отнести. Вот, например: "И тогда мы с вами получаем" - такой приём получаем=получим

Comment: Людмила, думаю, что вы правы. Тем более "в новое время" можно считать уточнением или условием временной направленности. В вашем примере "тогда" есть.

Answer (score 1):

> Так и мы разделили предприятия на тех,
> кто будет испытывать трудности, и тех,
> кто...

*Так и мы разделили предприятия на те, **что** будут испытывать трудности, и те, **что**...*

Comment: Спасибо огромное